# Algid parse error, not a sequence

Tags: java, security, rsa

When trying to read a RSA private key from a file using the method

```
public PrivateKey getPrivateKey()
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        InvalidKeySpecException, IOException {

    final InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream("privatekey");
    byte[] privKeyBytes = null;
    try {
        privKeyBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    } catch (final IOException exception) {
        LOGGER.error("", exception);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
    }

    LOGGER.debug("privKeyBytes: {}", privKeyBytes);

    String BEGIN = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
    String END = "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
    String str = new String(privKeyBytes);
    if (str.contains(BEGIN) && str.contains(END)) {
        str = str.substring(BEGIN.length(), str.lastIndexOf(END));
    }

    KeyFactory fac = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    EncodedKeySpec privKeySpec =
            new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(str.getBytes()));
    return fac.generatePrivate(privKeySpec);
}
```

I get the exception

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : algid parse error, not a sequence
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(RSAKeyFactory.java:200) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(KeyFactory.java:342) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
```

at the fac.generatePrivate(privKeySpec) call.

What does this error mean?

Thanks

Dmitri

Answer (score 107, accepted):

It means your key is not in PKCS#8 format. The easiest thing to do is to use the `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 <...other options...>` command to convert the key once. Alternatively you can use the [`PEMReader`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/util/io/pem/PemReader.html) class of the [Bouncycastle lightweight API](http://www.bouncycastle.org/documentation.html).

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Here's the command: openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in myrsakey.pem -out myrsakey_pcks8

Comment: if it is not in PKCS8 format, what format it can be? If multiple options it can be, how to know the format before converting to PKCS8 using OPENSSL command?

Comment: @PSatishPatro: The private key was in PKCS#1 format. In this case the clue was the "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" which signals this is a PKCS#1 private in "PEM" format.

Answer (score 156):

I was having this same issue, and the format of the key was NOT the actual problem.
All I had to do to get rid of that exception was to call

```
java.security.Security.addProvider(
         new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider()
);
```

and everything worked

Comment: How does this fix the issue?

Comment: It works...but why?!

Comment: How does this magic work? 0_o

Comment: What is the magic behind this?

Comment: Wow thank you time saver! I added following dependancy to get the BouncyCastleProvider:  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.70</version>
</dependency>

Comment: just use this and continue with your other bugs :D

Answer (score 85):

You must make your PCKS8 file from your private key!

#### private.pem => name of private key file

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 1024
```

#### public_key.pem => name of public key file

```
openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout -outform PEM -out public_key.pem
```

#### ‫‪private_key.pem‬‬ => name of private key with PCKS8 format! you can just read this format in java

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -in private.pem -out private_key.pem -nocrypt
```

Comment: This was my problem - the file was generated using `genrsa` which creates a PKCS#1 format (this is the format the OP loads, as can be seen by the `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY` header), while PKCS#8 is a different format (and in PEM encoding can be detect due to the different header: `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY`). My key generator now looks like this: `openssl genrsa 2048 | openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -out private.pem`

Comment: Do you have a similar key generator for EC private key?

Comment: @RahulAgrawal, unfortunately, don't have

Comment: What about the public key ? Will it be in PKCS#8 format by default ?

Comment: @SaiRamReddy "-outform PEM" sets output format, take a look at documentation: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-rsa.html

Comment: Is it possible to generate the same programatically? I would want to do the same programatically instead of using CLI.

Comment: @ShivamSahil indeed possible! but the parameters should be handled. here is a sample code: https://www.example-code.com/java/rsa_genKey.asp