# How do I format an exported Vault private key for use?

Tags: java, public-key-encryption, private-key, hashicorp-vault

I am running [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) locally, using the transit secret engine. Running locally in-memory, I have created an exportable private key that I can retrieve with the following information:

```
{
    "request_id": "ad4401f3-b88b-19f1-0bec-ce710dc647ee",
    "lease_id": "",
    "renewable": false,
    "lease_duration": 0,
    "data": {
        "keys": {
            "1": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEowIBAAKCAQEAnLs+5HqCJzJBcdLU+m5hO70ELEBdh2Iy/dp4hGwR2dZiHYGD\nD7jUyTkjDAOpjqsCcqK/bAqCFS/1781s7n37IzVwtu4wU7fXjGdW7582QxfEpUms\n9IYFvzWfIhPDE5VmeXJb7yKiW8rySAbyqQ/ctmOUZtZi/PbHQgS3rmcLvOidp8kJ\nGLb7LYjsZB9tS+Hk4YWKo/3LEyyEkeWtUTQVKzkOOlOZtBmlSkkpz0nV0af/yqkT\nVvvh+RarwlrVwiJvgB8bpSq/gl68Fv28TKa7j0lsHINLgEy1W69KKXg8BVfZvxKn\nwwdtkhlnLN+qtuqk3uO4EOxzZojKdLTXEpp1QwIDAQABAoIBACfoKXBlnSQ70JwZ\n0a7eUhWy4BAgZ3AkWdV3Pj6Bgd4UjzDyHBvxtQRzbvANMqwn8Nydgd4RouOgLZ/c\nj4L+QubJIaUCav22DsUqPuGOiXN15tUrOEWepnH0RkuX+pDO9qOvsabnC64Rs7UR\nR9IyPsGWA2BX8CZ2829k4hwfEscLkae5KHd9bDvIRBH8XnafcUgf6cB3V3GVwZsU\nGuT1UUGcuubRXTrsOger9Rb0L3lgTXwpIXeOqAjeOEtjL6+bVOpMdiequmJf5VfK\nQ0If9gW6XHMQoPdx3+fBzC0/UU6BBNzfojZ9itHp1kQX3h7zilJbPJpm33Jgzg1J\nAUSPZtECgYEAzTmZwF0Mjb/FUZR884HZ23sVn81oW0mPDmgc3NtmY2YsRhyvd2nc\nsCAuQjDgmXyraEZ8IKoGQxHJn7t1yxpxISaGMCDQ1XvfHdSJxxQHGJW+/JjANN/F\nBGyMhCD3rQA8MIiDbe7PyfIhb2dOgza34e19V/5JwaCSd+nP4N10rXkCgYEAw4Ix\nTmY/RdhZABsPn0CymkJZ+y+rTKRNUNclNxuUAgVkOBlHt6ILa+B7gzI0bKX9+YZQ\nXIEsbREl6KvaJe9d5x/JHYcRhJJoHqPoJuvGlfxH7azEoyrdZcR57ayldhfVsvjJ\nsLD7b2lX9JzNnGtipx2PE4ppuB7oN5oU1VpulZsCgYAJHzNPUpN5RXney2vWYwIs\n+EaYyMeHrzhVmpkV1Aa0ClmTcDj4ZNMzXOrRdFy3VcxEoUVpKkWG+6ZrnCh7M5yt\nrYmvX/YIVy4upEDPgXtjQ1yu25dHgl6+eJiyUsjPfsAuJBM7cq73ufR0gDIEMQ1x\nVF4K6DmdCqcX/2OHCjDieQKBgQC7XtYUVgfDz5GUeVrifGXvUzHbexcHz9tNY7QF\n+YdC3Jns7cV+521cyPp2hTIbAobCkogH78B9EtcrAzCB9MMhE6RyiRUv4gSpgNqo\nGoTrD6p7zX1zB0zCEKfuMe0tnbAv4yGhFi0S3HnwNCsWAxC8KqcJyjiBvhU93Iyk\n4RNkiwKBgF8YeD0lrrD8C+gddQrhblTRA8mGvMKEfh992hG8bPpiac0n4uBe3bmH\nUvf66mHBScq/77bF4gMZpafWoTX7AAHS1NpIdg46WWUKQZTW593awCsjKByqxP0I\nFIsGZZNvdK2iw7iVAzIj1TqUdnpKjGw85iO0n2GsLTupy3qR7IdH\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
        },
        "name": "testkey",
        "type": "rsa-2048"
    },
    "wrap_info": null,
    "warnings": null,
    "auth": null
}
```

I remove the newline characters and the header / footer, and get the following Base64 encoded string:

```
val privKeystring = "MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAnLs+5HqCJzJBcdLU+m5hO70ELEBdh2Iy/dp4hGwR2dZiHYGDD7jUyTkjDAOpjqsCcqK/bAqCFS/1781s7n37IzVwtu4wU7fXjGdW7582QxfEpUms9IYFvzWfIhPDE5VmeXJb7yKiW8rySAbyqQ/ctmOUZtZi/PbHQgS3rmcLvOidp8kJGLb7LYjsZB9tS+Hk4YWKo/3LEyyEkeWtUTQVKzkOOlOZtBmlSkkpz0nV0af/yqkTVvvh+RarwlrVwiJvgB8bpSq/gl68Fv28TKa7j0lsHINLgEy1W69KKXg8BVfZvxKnwwdtkhlnLN+qtuqk3uO4EOxzZojKdLTXEpp1QwIDAQABAoIBACfoKXBlnSQ70JwZ0a7eUhWy4BAgZ3AkWdV3Pj6Bgd4UjzDyHBvxtQRzbvANMqwn8Nydgd4RouOgLZ/cj4L+QubJIaUCav22DsUqPuGOiXN15tUrOEWepnH0RkuX+pDO9qOvsabnC64Rs7URR9IyPsGWA2BX8CZ2829k4hwfEscLkae5KHd9bDvIRBH8XnafcUgf6cB3V3GVwZsUGuT1UUGcuubRXTrsOger9Rb0L3lgTXwpIXeOqAjeOEtjL6+bVOpMdiequmJf5VfKQ0If9gW6XHMQoPdx3+fBzC0/UU6BBNzfojZ9itHp1kQX3h7zilJbPJpm33Jgzg1JAUSPZtECgYEAzTmZwF0Mjb/FUZR884HZ23sVn81oW0mPDmgc3NtmY2YsRhyvd2ncsCAuQjDgmXyraEZ8IKoGQxHJn7t1yxpxISaGMCDQ1XvfHdSJxxQHGJW+/JjANN/FBGyMhCD3rQA8MIiDbe7PyfIhb2dOgza34e19V/5JwaCSd+nP4N10rXkCgYEAw4IxTmY/RdhZABsPn0CymkJZ+y+rTKRNUNclNxuUAgVkOBlHt6ILa+B7gzI0bKX9+YZQXIEsbREl6KvaJe9d5x/JHYcRhJJoHqPoJuvGlfxH7azEoyrdZcR57ayldhfVsvjJsLD7b2lX9JzNnGtipx2PE4ppuB7oN5oU1VpulZsCgYAJHzNPUpN5RXney2vWYwIs+EaYyMeHrzhVmpkV1Aa0ClmTcDj4ZNMzXOrRdFy3VcxEoUVpKkWG+6ZrnCh7M5ytrYmvX/YIVy4upEDPgXtjQ1yu25dHgl6+eJiyUsjPfsAuJBM7cq73ufR0gDIEMQ1xVF4K6DmdCqcX/2OHCjDieQKBgQC7XtYUVgfDz5GUeVrifGXvUzHbexcHz9tNY7QF+YdC3Jns7cV+521cyPp2hTIbAobCkogH78B9EtcrAzCB9MMhE6RyiRUv4gSpgNqoGoTrD6p7zX1zB0zCEKfuMe0tnbAv4yGhFi0S3HnwNCsWAxC8KqcJyjiBvhU93Iyk4RNkiwKBgF8YeD0lrrD8C+gddQrhblTRA8mGvMKEfh992hG8bPpiac0n4uBe3bmHUvf66mHBScq/77bF4gMZpafWoTX7AAHS1NpIdg46WWUKQZTW593awCsjKByqxP0IFIsGZZNvdK2iw7iVAzIj1TqUdnpKjGw85iO0n2GsLTupy3qR7IdH"
```

But when I try to instantiate a `PrivateKey` object in Java (Kotlin), I get an "InvalidKeyException: algid parse error, not a sequence".

```
val privByteKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privKeystring)
val privKey = PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privByteKey)
val privateKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(privKey) // throws an exception
```

Am I missing some other step to format Vault's output before I can use the private key?

**Edit**: Stack trace, as requested:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : algid parse error, not a sequence
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(RSAKeyFactory.java:251) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(KeyFactory.java:390) ~[na:na]
    at com.mycompany.testClass.service.MyService.testMethod(MyService.kt:83) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: You might want to recreate your key once your problem is solved :)

Comment: @PhilippeB. Indeed! The key above is in-memory only, so it'll vanish the next time I turn off my computer.

Comment: And the exception is? Post the stacktrace.

Comment: @michalk - updated to include full stacktrace.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559272/algid-parse-error-not-a-sequence)

Comment: You remove the newlines and the header/footer why? Have you tried not doing that?

Comment: @user207421 The newlines and header/footer (e.g. "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----") are not base 64-encoded, and therefore can not be part of the base 64-encoded key.

Comment: @michalk - that resolved the issue -- Vault exports the private key in PKCS1 format, so it must be converted to PKCS8 before Java can make use of it. If you'd like to post that as an answer, I'll accept it. Otherwise, I'll self-answer to the same effect in a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vault exports RSA keys in PKCS1 format by default. So you can consider converting PKCS1 format to PKCS8 format using openssl :

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform PEM -nocrypt -in PKCS1_KEY.key -out PKCS8_KEY.key
```

and then use your code to ready it as you do.

Or use BouncyCastle and it's [PEMReader](http://javadox.com/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.51/org/bouncycastle/util/io/pem/PemReader.html) to read this key :

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("path/to/your/key/key.key");
PEMReader pemReader = new PEMReader(fileReader);
KeyPair keyPair = (KeyPair) pemReader.readObject();
PrivateKey aPrivate = keyPair.getPrivate();
```