# java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: algid parse error, not a sequence

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, microservices

I have the following code implemented in java service class inside a spring microservices arquitecture:

```
@Autowired
private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

public String prueba(String data) {
    
    generateKeys(data); 
    
    byte[] text=encryptPrivate("texto de prueba lala",data);
    String texto=decryptPublic(text,data);
    
    return texto;
}

public String generateKeys(String username) {

    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = null;
    try {
        keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    keyPairGenerator.initialize(512); // múltiplo de 64, 512 ~ 65536

    KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

    RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
    System.out.println("Private: " + rsaPrivateKey);

    RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
    System.out.println("Public: " + rsaPublicKey);
    
    byte[] publicKeyBytes = keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded();
    byte[] privateKeyBytes = keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded();
    System.out.println("Encoded: " + publicKeyBytes);
    
    usuarioRepository.add(publicKeyBytes, privateKeyBytes, username);

    return "ok";
}

public byte[] encryptPrivate(String data, String username) {
    
    //sacar clave de BBDD
    byte[] keyBytes = getPrKey(username); //new byte[(int)f.length()]; 
    EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
   
    try {
         KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA"); 
         RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) kf.generatePrivate(spec);
         Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
         cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, rsaPrivateKey);
         byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
         
         return cipherText;
         
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    
    return null;
}

public String decryptPublic(byte[] data, String username) {

    byte[] keyBytes = getPuKey(username); //new byte[(int)f.length()]; 
    X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    try {
         KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA"); 
         RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(spec);
         Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
         cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, rsaPublicKey); 
         byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(data);
         //new String(plainText);
         return new String(plainText);
         
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "fail";      
            
}
```

The problem comes when I try to recover the private key from the DDBB:

```
 RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) kf.generatePrivate(spec);
```

Im storing the key in a varbinary. I got the following error:

java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : DerValue.getBigIntegerInternal, not expected 48
at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(RSAKeyFactory.java:252)
at java.base/java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(KeyFactory.java:390)
at com.iasec.wallet.service.WalletServiceImpl.encryptPrivate(WalletServiceImpl.java:134)
at com.iasec.wallet.service.WalletServiceImpl.prueba(WalletServiceImpl.java:50)
at com.iasec.wallet.controller.WalletController.encrypt1(WalletController.java:43)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : DerValue.getBigIntegerInternal, not expected 48
at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(PKCS8Key.java:133)
at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.(PKCS8Key.java:94)
at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.(RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.java:152)
at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.newKey(RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.java:89)
at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePrivate(RSAKeyFactory.java:343)
at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(RSAKeyFactory.java:248)
... 54 more
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: algid parse error, not a sequence
at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:240)
at java.base/java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:352)
at com.iasec.wallet.service.WalletServiceImpl.decryptPublic(WalletServiceImpl.java:209)
at com.iasec.wallet.service.WalletServiceImpl.prueba(WalletServiceImpl.java:51)
at com.iasec.wallet.controller.WalletController.encrypt1(WalletController.java:43)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: algid parse error, not a sequence
at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:397)
at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:402)

Comment: you may look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559272/algid-parse-error-not-a-sequence